# Using Arrays.sort, empty array returned

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm using the `Arrays.sort` method to sort an array of my own `Comparable` objects. Before I use sort the array is full, but after I sort the array and print it to System nothing is printing out. EDIT. the array prints nothing at all. not empty line(s), just nothing.

here is the code for my method which uses `sort` :

```
public LinkedQueue<Print> arraySort(LinkedQueue<Print> queue1)
{
    Print[] thing = new Print[queue1.size()];
    LinkedQueue<Print> newQueue = new LinkedQueue<Print>();

    for(int i = 0; i <queue1.size(); i++)
    {
        Print ob = queue1.dequeue();
        thing[i] = ob;
        System.out.println(thing[i]);   //printing works here
    }

    Arrays.sort(thing);

    for(int j = 0;j<thing.length-1;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(thing[j]);   //printing does not work here 
        newQueue.enqueue(thing[j]);
    }

    return newQueue;
}
```

and here is the class for the `Comparable` object called `Print`.

```
public class Print implements Comparable<Print>
{
    private String name;
    private int numPages,arrivalTime,startTime,endTime;

    public Print(String n, int p, int time, int sTime, int eTime)
    {
        name = n;
        numPages = p;
        arrivalTime = time;
        startTime = sTime;
        endTime = eTime;
    }

    public int getPages()
    {
        return numPages; 
    }

    public int compareTo(Print other)
    {
        if(this.getPages()<other.getPages())
            return -1;

        else if(this.getPages()>other.getPages())
            return 1;

        else
            return 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name+"("+numPages+" pages) - printed "+startTime+"-"+endTime+" minutes";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not printing out the last element? `for(int j = 0;j<thing.length-1;j++)` would normally be `for(int j = 0;j<thing.length;j++)` or just `for (Print p : thing)`

Comment: Also, what *exactly* does "printing does not work here" mean? Is *anything* being printed? The wrong values?

Comment: You can just print using `Arrays.toString(thing)`, since you have overrided `toString` in your `Print` class. And tell us exactly what the output is.

Comment: @JonSkeet *"after I sort the array and print it to System **nothing** is printing out."*

Comment: Also, you could replace the `compareTo()` implementation with just a `return this.numPages - other.numPages;`

Comment: @NullUserException: Well, that could still mean "empty lines" or "absolutely nothing at all". It would help if we had a short but complete example...

Comment: @JonSkeet It's simply not printing. Not an empty line, just nothing happening.

Comment: @bitva: If you add a `System.out.println("Before: " + thing.length)` just before the loop and something similar *after* the loop, what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `for` loop doesn't print the last element in the array. If the array has only one element, it won't print anything at all. Change to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < thing.length; j++) //clean code uses spaces liberally :)
{
    System.out.println(thing[j]);
    newQueue.enqueue(thing[j]);
}
```

or (if supported by the JDK/JRE version used):

```
for (Print p : thing)
{
    System.out.println(p); 
    newQueue.enqueue(p);
}
```

Comment: *"clean code uses spaces liberally"* Really a matter of personal preference. I think `int j = 0` is ugly.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Comment: @bitva thanks for accepting. Glad to know my answer helped. Also do take a look at imran's answer. If `queue1` is mutable via the `dequeue()` method, the value returned by `size()` can change during loop iteration leading to undesirable results (doesn't iterate over all objects in queue). You can solve by either storing original size in a variable and using it for the loop, or by creating an isEmpty method in the LinkedQueue implementation.

Comment: @bitva: So were you only using a single element array? It would have been *really* helpful to say that to start with...

Answer (score -1):

I hope the problem is this part of code

```
for(int i = 0; i <queue1.size(); i++)
{
    Print ob = queue1.dequeue();
    thing[i] = ob;
    System.out.println(thing[i]);   //printing works here
}
```

replace the above with

```
for(int i = 0; !queue1.isEmpty() ; i++)
{
    Print ob = queue1.dequeue();
    thing[i] = ob;
    System.out.println(thing[i]);   //printing works here
}
```

Comment: And who said `LinkedQueue` has an `.isEmpty()` method?

Comment: What on earth is LinkedQueue anyway? As far as I can tell, there's no standard LinkedQueue implementation in Java, and there are a lot of different custom implementations floating in the interwebs, especially on university sites.

Comment: @ADTC A non-standard Queue implemented using a LinkedList, I presume.

Comment: If that is the case, surely one could extend the implementation to include an isEmpty method.

Comment: @NullUserException : Sorry I misunderstood. Can you tell me how it is ensured that all the elements of **queue1** is getting inserted to **thing** ?

Comment: @imranhasanhira I don't know. I'm just saying we can't infer from the code given that it has an `isEmpty()` method.

Comment: @imran It doesn't. Your answer points out what's wrong with that part. But it's not the solution to the question asked. Regardless, I have asked bitva to look at your answer and the semantic error it reveals :)